# Backbone.history.start() blocks back button from leaving the page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I've run into this on a few apps now, so I wonder if I'm doing something wrong with Backbone history. Here's the situation...

I have two pages, let's say:

```
index.html
app.html
```

The index page is just a normal, flat HTML page with a link to `app.html`. On the App page, `Backbone.history.start()` is called to fire up hash state management, which is used to toggle between two views on the App page, say:

```
app.html#search
app.html#results
```

So, navigating back and forth between the `#search` and `#results` pages works great. No problems there. The issue occurs when you try to use the back button to step all the way back to `index.html`. The path back to the index page involves a stop at `app.html` (no hash state), at which the Backbone router dutifully fills in missing hash state, putting you back at `app.html#search`. Again, clicking the back button will go to `app.html`, which fills in the missing hash state again... basically, you're now stuck in a loop and can't go back from the page. This same behavior occurs when using push state.

This seems like a potentially common problem with apps that automatically fire up their own routing system on top of a default page URL. Does anyone know of a good way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `app.html` isn't doing anything on it's own; and so, may somehow break the app if navigated.

In this case, what you could do is instead of redirecting the root route to another, just use it as the default page:

```
routes: {
  "": "search",
  "results": "results"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of it like that. Makes perfect sense that the base URL needs to be THE start point. Unfortunately, our UX specs are generally tailored around conditional entry-point logic, which is fundamentally what causes this issue. I'll be ready to nip this issue in the bud in the future.