# Bulding single page apps with backbone and cordova and tracking navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, backbone.js, cordova

I am building single page apps using backbone, jquery and cordova 2.7.0.

My starting page look likes this

```
 <div id="activity-container">
     <form action="/login" id="login-form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input id="username" type="text"/>
        <input id="password" type="password"/>
        <a href="#login">Sign In</strong></a>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I wrote loginview as follows

```
 LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#login-form"),
    events: {
        "click #login": "authenticate"
    },
    authenticate: function(){
        new SecondView();
    }
});
```

The secondview just takes someTemplate and render then within div with id="acitivity-container". I wrote this as

```
   SecondView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#activity-container"),
    template: _.template( $("#someTemplate").html() ),
    initialize: function () {
        this.$el.html( this.template 
    },
    render: function () {           
        this.$el.html( this.template );
        return this;
    }
  });
```

I just wanted to check. So, my template is for now any static html. Ex

```
   <script type="text/someTemplate">
      <p>Anything here<p>
   </script>
```

I initialize apps with following code

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady() {
            new loginView();
            Backbone.history.start();
     }
```

This works fine. When I click sign in, it takes me to appointmentview. Now, when I press "ESC" in keyboard , this will take me out of applications instead of going back to loginview. This simply mean i can't go back. How can we solve this problem?

MY idea is that I will build each view and hook them to "activity-container" div. But, it seems this may be bad idea. Can anyone suggest me any starting examples for building single page apps with backbone and cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would make using cordova any different then how you would do it on the web browser, but I'd suggest you look into Routers and History, in the documentation.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

http://backbonejs.org/#History-start

Also look into this issue, might be a similar problem:

[Backbone.history.start() blocks back button from leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250302/backbone-history-start-blocks-back-button-from-leaving-the-page)

You might also look into 
window.history.back()

I guess the only other possibility which i am not clear on is if you are simply trying to override how Cordova treats the Esc key.